# How to get audio feild of wordpress toolset types plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am using Toolset Types for custom fields
I am trying to get audio field of product
using

```
types_render_field( "slig-name", array("output" => "html") )
```

and

```
types_render_field( "slig-name", array() )
```

getting audio player & text of audio file URL
[image]
I need only audio player 
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the audio file URL:

```
$attachment_id = types_render_field('slug-name', array('raw'=>'true'));
$fileurl = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
```

Which you could then pass to an audio player or standard embed shortcode.

[Source](https://wp-types.com/forums/topic/how-do-i-get-mp3-audio-duration-and-file-size-from-a-types-audio-or-file-field/)